# Android Chrome - Unable to open PDF

Tags: html, spring, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a reponsive bootstrap application and while trying to open the pdf from mobile getting error. I am able to open the pdf from iphone however from android chrome it says "`media not supported exception`"

I have my application type as "octet-stream"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `application/octet-stream` MIME should only be used when you don't know what the file contents is going to be, as it's for arbitrary binary data. The receiver has to attempt to work out what type it is, based on it's content and/or file extension.

You should be always use the appropriate MIME if it is known:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.PDF"
```

Comment: Yes I changed it to "application/pdf" and still does not open the pdf in android chrome. But it works in ios chrome or safari or any other browser.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/pdf/{formRefId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/pdf")
@PreAuthorize("@mysiteAuthorizationService.hasPermission('eacceptance_form_doc_ref',#formRefId)")
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFormPdf(@PathVariable("formRefId") String formRefId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {     ResponseEntity<byte[]> responsePdf = serviceClient.downloadFormPdf(formRefId);
     return responsePdf;
 
 }